# Wordpress Zapier and Webhooks with Cloud9

Tags: wordpress, cloud9-ide, webhooks, zapier

I am trying to test out webhooks integration with wordpress using the cloud9 ide as a proof of concept before moving on to an actual wordpress hosting.

I created the wordpress site in cloud9 and it works fine, but when I try to connect to my Zapier account to my wordpress account (on cloud9), I always get an error.

The error is

"We hit an error adding your new account
authorization failed: ResponseError()"

My first thought is that there are CORs problems, but I don't know if there is any way to debug the login attempt from Zapier.

Has anyone successfully managed to connect Zapier to a wordpress site hosted on cloud9? If so, was there any specific CORS settings necessary to make that work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason that this wouldn't work is because the seemingly global URL I use to access my cloud9 wordpress site is only available within the browser I was logged into cloud9 with, from other browsers/machines the cloud9 login page was blocking access, therefore Zapier could not access it.

The alternative seems to be to host wordpress somewhere globally accessible or host locally and forward port 80/443 on your router so that Zapier can access your local account.

Comment: Yes, that's a security feature so others can't see your site. Alternatively you can make your workspace public so Zapier can access it by clicking on the share button in the top right and ticking the "public" box beside "Preview"

Comment: Thanks, I figured there was probably a way to do this. Azure also has free wordpress hosting, which is what I am experimenting with now but I like the control I have with c9 so I might go back to that if the need arises, thanks for the info.